# Qual é a real implementação do "in" no Python?

Tags: python, python-internals

Esta semana me peguei perguntando qual a real implementação do "in" no Python. Para tentar responder, fui olhar [a documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) sobre os detalhes dele, e apenas dizem que:

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

O que eu particularmente discordo (**se eu estiver errado, por que estou?**), por que o ideal seria parar a execução no momento em que a primeira comparação seja válida. Ou seja, acredito que esta seria a real implementação:

```py
def _in(a, b):
    for e in b:
        if e == a or e is a:
            return True
    return False
```

Para testar esta minha teoria, fiz um teste usando a função `time.time()` com uma lista GRANDE (5 MILHÕES de inteiros) e coloquei o elemento que quero achar por último. E este código:

```py
import time

def generate_huge_list():
    _list = []
    for i in range(5000):
        _list.extend([i,]*1000)

    _list.append(-10)
    return _list

def _in_for(a, b):
    for e in b:
        if e == a or e is a:
            return True
    return False

def _using_in(x, list_of_integers):
    return x in list_of_integers

def _using_any(x, list_of_integers):
    return any(x is e or x == e for e in list_of_integers)

list_of_integers = generate_huge_list()

x = -10

old_time = time.time()
does_it_exist = _using_in(x, list_of_integers)
elapsed_time = time.time() - old_time
print( "Usando o 'in' do Python, demorou %f e retornou %s" % (elapsed_time, does_it_exist))

old_time = time.time()
does_it_exist = _in_for(x, list_of_integers)
elapsed_time = time.time() - old_time
print( "Usando minha implementação, demorou %f e retornou %s" % (elapsed_time, does_it_exist))

old_time = time.time()
does_it_exist = _using_any(x, list_of_integers)
elapsed_time = time.time() - old_time
print( "Usando a implementação da documentação, demorou %f e retornou %s" % (elapsed_time, does_it_exist))
```

Me retornou isso:

> Número de elementos na lista: 5000001
>   Usando o `in` do Python, demorou 0.131924 e retornou True
>   Usando minha implementação, demorou 0.457717 e retornou True
>   Usando a implementação da documentação, demorou 0.949417 e retornou True

Me assusta a discrepância de velocidade, sendo o `in` incrivelmente mais rápido que o resto e a minha função em segundo lugar (o que possivelmente comprova minha teoria). Decidi procurar no [código fonte](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f665b96e92a6a6943e312e2c606f348db95939ab/Objects/listobject.c#L445) e pelo [magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) do `in`, encontrei esta função:

```c
static int
list_contains(PyListObject *a, PyObject *el)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    int cmp;

    for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i)
        cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(el, PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i),
                                           Py_EQ);
    return cmp;
}
```

Pela facilidade da leitura, concluí que esta deve realmente ser a função. Mas mesmo assim fiquei com dúvida:

**Por que é tão mais rápido? Apenas por que é escrito em C? Caso sim, existem algumas outras implementações melhores e conhecidas que seriam melhor usadas se forem a original?**

Comment: Acredito que o interpretador já possua os bytecodes otimizados para funções e operadores builtin do Python, aliás, acredito que este código esteja em CPython. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython

Comment: *"o ideal seria parar a execução no momento em que a primeira comparação seja válida"* - Mas o `any` não para logo que encontra um elemento? Pelo menos a documentação diz que ele para: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any - E pra testar o tempo de execução, é melhor usar o módulo `timeit`: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html

Comment: Então por que ele demora o dobro do tempo??

Comment: Ah sim, deve ser pq eu percorro duas vezes (para montar a lista de booleanos e depois percorrer).

Comment: `(x is e or x == e for e in list_of_integers)` não percorre a lista inteira, só cria um generator, [que é *lazy* (não retorna todos os booleanos de uma vez)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/364802). Quando o `any` vai iterar por esse generator, é pedido um elemento por vez, até encontrar um que satisfaça a condição. O que deve demorar é a criação do generator e as chamadas para `next()`, como o @jsbueno [já citou no outro comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385362#comment761400_385403)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O interpretador Python é mantido por centenas de voluntários ao longo de décadas. Embora seja um software complexo, e, claro, longe de ser perfeito, em geral para coisa simples e óbvias, como "parar a busca no momento que o primeiro resultado é encontrado", a coisa está otimizada.  (de novo: são centenas de colaboradores, ao longo de quase 3 décadas).

E sim, a função em C que você achou deve fazer a busca padrão do contains - e, *ela para* ao achar o primeiro valor igual. A questão é que a gente tem aulas na faculdade de C, decora o `for` do C com o padrão `i=0; i<X; i++` , e esquece que na verdade são expressões arbitrárias que podem ser muito bem usadas - e é o caso aí:

```
Py_ssize_t i;
int cmp;

for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i)
    cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(el, PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i),
                                       Py_EQ);
return cmp;
```

Observe a condição de parada do `for` (a do meio, depois do primerio `;`): enquanto `cmp == 0` *e* `i < PySIZE(a)` - então não é só a segunda parte, a primeira também - assim que `PyObject_RichCompareBool` retornar verdadeiro, a expressão do `for` dá Falsa, e ele é interrompido. O valor de `cmp` é verdadeiro e é retornado pela função em C.

O outro detalhe digno de nota nessa análise é justmamente esse: para respeitar a semântica do Python, a comparação entre os objetos é feita por essa função `PyObject_RichCompareBool` - e não diretamente com `==` em cima de um ou mais campos do objeto. É ela que vai retornar `True` se os objetos forem o mesmo (a parte  do `x is e` na documentação) *ou* se foram iguais - `x == e` - só que para retornar o `x == e`, e manter toda a coerência e simplicidade - para o programador - do Python é que está o pulo do gato - nesse ponto o Python verifica se os objetos tem implementações do método `__eq__` e chama esses métodos (que podem inclusive ser em Python). Ou seja, mesmo na comparação em alta velociade, dentro do código nativo na função `RichCompareBool`, se o objeto está personalizado em Python com um `__eq__` específico, esse código é executado. No caso de inteiros, a versão do `__eq__` para inteiros, bastante otimizada, mas ainda assim preparada para comparar inteiros com um número arbitrário de dígitos, é chamada.

E mesmo a expressão em Python sendo equivalente ao `in`, a execução do operador é muito mais rápida por que a simples execução de  `x is e or x == e ...` envolve várias operações na VM do Python (VM == máquina virtual, a máquina de pilha que interpreta bytecode) - e cada operação na VM vai ser equivalente a, grosso modo, uma centena de operações nativas da CPU - enquanto que as comparações de um `for` em C como o acima, requerem pouquíssimas expressões nativas na CPU, da ordem de 20.

O método `dis.dis` permite uma visualização dos passos dessa expressão traduzidos em bytecode:

```
In [430]: dis.dis("x in e or x == e")                                                                                             
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (e)
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     14
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             10 LOAD_NAME                1 (e)
             12 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

**Como o uso de `any` é mais lento**?

O `any` fica mais lento do que a funçãozinha que você criou que faz a comparação direta por que exige, para cada elemento, uma mudança de contexto na máquina virtual do Python - o `any`, assim como a `RichCompareBool` acima, tem que respeitar os protocolos do Python para os objetos, e no caso, isso é chamar o método `__next__` da generator expression que você passa como parâmetro.

A VM do Python é um "grande switch case" em código nativo, que executa expressões e funções em C para cada bytecode da máquina Python. Ela é bem eficiente, e tem lá variáveis para acompanhar qual ponto do bytecode está em execução e algumas outras variáveis de estado da função em execução. Cada vez que o `any` vai buscar um novo item (que no caso é o resultado da expressão `x is e or x == e`, sempre `True` ou `False`), a VM tem que "trocar de contexto" - isso é, mudar todas as variáveis internas sobre qual objeto de código está em execução, em que ponto do bytecode está, etc... isso é bem mais "caro" em ciclos de clock do que ter o "True" ou "False" da mesma expressão no mesmo bloco de código, como está na sua função.

## Por que Python continua sendo uma excelente escolha, mesmo com essa discrepância?

A proposta da linguagem é trazer simplicidade para implementação de algoritmos complexos, delegando os laços de computação intensiva para código nativo. E nesse caso, faz isso muito bem - se uma pessoa usa o  `in`, que é a forma "óbvia" de fazer uma busca em uma sequência, o caminho de código utilizado usa bastante código nativo e é naturalmente cerca de 5 vezes mais rápido do que re-escrever a mesma busca em Python (eu achava que essa diferença seria muito maior, na verdade).

Então se vocẽ leva em conta que a comparação do `in` no Python faz tudo na máxima velocidade possível respeitando a natureza dinâmica dos objetos em Python - a comparação funciona também para classes que re-implementem a operação de "==" e façam qualquer coisa maluca no código - a implementação é muito boa.

Se você *sabe* que vai buscar números inteiros, numa coleção de tipos de dados homogêneos que *Cabem* na CPU, como inteiros de 32 ou 64bit, e *precisa* de velocidade, a forma de fazer isso é usar bibliotecas especialidas, por exemplo o numpy  - O numpy vai fazer a comparação num vetor de inteiros e vai fazer isso não só em código nativo, mas usando instruções SIMD, *e* threads em CPUs concorrentes onde for o caso.

Então, numa máquina mais rápida que a sua - mas só colei  exatamente o código que você colocou na questão, e em seguida, adicionei o código necessário para fazer a busca usando o numpy e exibi o tempo:

```
Usando o 'in' do Python, demorou 0.044108 e retornou True
Usando minha implementação, demorou 0.157202 e retornou True
Usando a implementação da documentação, demorou 0.262640 e retornou True

In [443]: import numpy as np                                                                                                      

In [444]: np_list  = np.array(list_of_integers, dtype="int32")                                                                    

In [445]: %time x in np_list                                                                                                      
CPU times: user 1.79 ms, sys: 997 µs, total: 2.79 ms
Wall time: 2.21 ms
Out[445]: True
```

2.21ms, ou 0.00221 segundos, comparado com o 0.044 da implementação com inteiros nativos - um ganho de 20x na velocidade. Isso é possível, de novo, graças a flexibilidade da linguagem, que permite que os arrays de numpy implementem o método `__contains__`. Então, em vez do código em C genérico para qualquer objeto Python que estavamos analizando, o numpy usa código otimizado para busca em inteiros  do tipo desejado.

Então, o interessante de ir aprendendo são coisas como essa: Python garante maior velocidade do desenvolvedor, e, uma vez que se sabe o que está fazendo, permite que o desenvolvedor delegue os laços mais críticos do programa para serem executados em código nativo, combinando o melhor dos dois mundos.

## Mas não desligue ainda

Se realmente *tempo* for crítico numa busca de um elemento no meio de conjunto de outros, há uma coisa que ainda é *mais rápida* do que usar o numpy para busca em números nativos, que é , usar o algoritmo correto - em listas e arrays do numpy, o `in` usa uma busca linear, comparando elemento por elemento. É fácil perceber que qualquer algoritmo que em vez de percorrer a lista linearmente vá "direto ao ponto"  e diga se um elemento está lá ou não vai ser muito mais rápido.  Em Python isso é feito com os conjuntos (`set`s):

```
In [446]: conjunto_grande = {i for i in range(5_000_000)}                                                                         

In [447]: conjunto_grande.add(x)                                                                                                  
In [448]: %time x in conjunto_grande                                                                                              
CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 3 µs
Wall time: 5.72 µs
Out[448]: True
```

Pronto, o tempo passou dos 2ms na busca linear com o numpy para 3 MICROssegundos - um ganho de **20000x** em cima do `in` em uma lista, e sem ter que recorrer a outra linguagem, assembler, nada - apenas fazendo uso dos tipos de dados de alto nível otimizados que a linguagem disponibiliza e com o programador "sabendo o que está fazendo".

Então, quando organizações como "Google e NASA" (sem nenhuma "mitologia") optam por usar Python num projeto, sim, os times levam em consideração todos esses fatores: o quanto vão ganhar em programadores/hora ao usar uma linguagem de muito alto nível no desenvolvimento, e quando e que partes otimizar em código nativo.  O resultado são projetos como TensorFlow, um maquinário excepcionalmente otimizado para operações envolvendo redes neurais e aprendizado de máquina, mas podendo ser controlado por uma API em alto nível que economiza um tempo gigantesco que seria gasto em boiler-plate-code se a mesma biblioteca fosse ser usada a partir de uma linguagem de mais baixo nível.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Você sabe se o numpy é  escrito em Python ou em C/C++?

Comment: O núcleo do numpy - a parte onde realmente é só "rodar um for e executar as operações" é em C. Ele tem wrappers e toda a lógica de manipulação de objetos ainda em Python  - que já passam tudo digerido para o código em C.

Comment: Adicionei mais um trecho na resposta, explicando por que o `any` fica mais lento

Answer (score 3):

Essencialmente sim, a grande diferença é que a operação está sendo executada em C. Dá uma diferença principalmente porque é uma linguagem compilada e não interpretada. Na verdade se não tivesse que respeitar a semântica do Python e lidar com as características da VM da linguagem seria ainda mais rápido. Não sei se esta é a função que acaba sendo executada quando usa um `in`, mas é uma possibilidade.

O que me surpreende é a `any()` ser tão lenta, fico até pensando se é escrita em Python mesmo. Eu imagino que há algum tipo de abstração que faz ser pior que um laço simples e por isso eu sempre falo que tem hora que a abstração pode não ser uma boa ideia.

Quando alguém documentou falando em `any()` estava só mostrando como poderia ser a implementação na linguagem, não que de fato seja escrita assim.

Sua percepção que deveria encerrar a busca quase ache alguma está correta e é exatamente o que o `any()` faz, mesmo sem ver o código, afinal se alguém não fez assim poderia já ser considerado um *bug*.

Comment: Sobre a `any()`, depois que li o comentário de @hkotsubo, acredito que seja por que eu tenha que montar a lista de booleanos (no caso passados como argumentos para o any) e só depois assim o `any()` procurar por um resultado True. Deveria ter um outro argumento (para comparar com `"esta é a string"` ao invés de `True`, por exemplo.)

Comment: Eu acho que é o custo da abstração

Comment: Em projetos que requerem velocidade, Python então não deve ser uma excelente escolha. (Apesar de NASA e Google as vezes apostarem nela).

Comment: Não, nem um pouco, e aí você já está entrando em mitologia

Comment: O "any" fica lento por que envolve uma troca de contexto na VM do Python - o código do any tem que consumir o proximo elemento (next) de um gerador. Isos provavelmente envolve resetar alguns estados na VM do Python, e isso para cada elemento da lista. Certamente há espaço para otimização aí - mesmo assim ficou só duas vezes mais lento que fazer toda a operação no mesmo contexto.